# Difference quotients are increasing for $f$ convex

Tags: calculus, derivatives, convex-analysis

Problem 11A.9(c) in Spivak's *Calculus* (4th edition) asks the following (I'm paraphrasing):

> Suppose $f$ is convex. Show that $f'(a)$ exists iff $f_+'(x)$ is
>   continuous at $a$.

($f_+'(x)$ is the right-derivative at $a$.) I worked out a proof of this fact, and found the $\implies$ direction particularly laborious. Then I consulted the answer book (to the third edition, where the problem also appears), and found the line of reasoning in the picture below. It appears to be a big mistake: they have two values $a>b$, and they've written $\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b} < f_+'(b)$. Surely the inequality should be the other direction, right? Or am I very confused?

Normally I would assume it's a simple mistake, but usually Spivak's book is pretty careful, and here it seems the whole idea of the proof is wrong.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Since the slopes are increasing on a convex function then:

$$\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}\ge\frac{f(b+h)-f(b)}{h}$$

where $h>0$ and small enough that $b+h<a$. Letting $h$ tend to $0$ gives the inequality that you describe. However, the inequality may not be strict unless the function is strictly convex.

Comment: Thanks for your response. For Spivak, "convex" means "strictly convex".

Comment: You're welcome. In that case just change the direction of the inequality.

Comment: I think you mean make it strict, not change the direction.

Comment: I actually meant with respect to the inequality written in the original question which is strict.